# Multiplying by COUNT value

Tags: sql

I have some data of cage size and cage costs which I need to get a count of all the cage sizes and multiply those counts by the cage cost:

```
cagesize    cagecost
M           1.23
L           2.3
M           1.23
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT cagesize, COUNT(*), (COUNT(*) * cagecost) AS 'total'
FROM cage;
GROUP BY cagesize;
```

But it keeps on coming up with an error from the GROUP BY line

I would love for the result to be:

```
cagesize    COUNT(*)    Total
M           2           2.46
L           1           2.3
```

Comment: And which `sql` is it exactly? MySQL? Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

just use sum instead of multiplying

```
SELECT cagesize, COUNT(*), sum(cagecost) AS 'total'
FROM cage
GROUP BY cagesize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @t table (cagesize varchar(50),cagecost float)

insert into @t values ('M',1.23)
insert into @t values ('L',2.3)
insert into @t values ('M',1.23)

select cagesize,count(*) as cnt,sum(cagecost) as total from @t
group by cagesize
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
  select cagesize, count(1) as 'Count', cagecost * count(1) as 'total' 
  from cage group by cagesize, cagecost
```